# How to return the steps of Tower of Hanoi using recursion and not printing

Tags: c++, towers-of-hanoi

I need help regarding returning the steps in the tower of Hanoi. Below are my codes and output.

This is my header file

```
#ifndef Hanoi_h
#define Hanoi_h
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#pragma once

using namespace std;

class Hanoi {
private:
    int _num_poles;
    int _num_discs;
    std::vector<vector<vector<string>>> _cache;

    std::string lookup_moves(int num_discs, int src, int dst);
    std::string get_moves(int num_discs, int src, int dst, int tmp);
public:
// Use freebie default constructor
    std::string solve(int num_discs, int src, int dst, int tmp);
    friend class Tests; // Don't remove this line
};

    #include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include "Hanoi.h"
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
```

This is my .cpp file

```
using namespace std;

string Hanoi::get_moves(int num_discs, int src, int dst, int tmp){
    if(num_discs == 0){
        return "";
    }
    get_moves(num_discs-1, src, tmp, dst);
    // the print statement
    string step = to_string(src) + "->" + to_string(dst) + "\n";
    get_moves(num_discs-1, tmp, dst, src);

return step;
};
```

This is the wrong output when I tried to run. As you can see it only return one step when I tried to put get_moves(2,2,3,1):

```
2->3

program ended with exit code: 0
```

So basically the get_moves method must return all the steps that happen. But not printing it, just return the steps because the code will be checked by a code checker.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to correct things to return.

```
using namespace std;

string Hanoi::get_moves(int num_discs, int src, int dst, int tmp){
    if(num_discs == 0){
        return "";
    }
    string step_before = get_moves(num_discs-1, src, tmp, dst);
    // the print statement
    string step = to_string(src) + "->" + to_string(dst) + "\n";
    string step_after = get_moves(num_discs-1, tmp, dst, src);

    return step_before + step + step_after;
}
```